Ultimo cliente solo realiza cambios UNITY MIRROR
Tengo una escena de selección de personajes donde tengo 6 slots para el player y 6 slots para el oponente. Cuando elijo un personaje lo que quiero en primera instancia es que el mismo personaje se instancie del lado del enemigo.
Todo lo manejo desde un empty object que tiene un network identity y el siguiente script:
public class SyncSelectionScene : NetworkBehaviour
{
    public void SyncWarrior(string warrior, int slot)
    {
        CmdSelectCharacter(warrior, slot);
    }

    [Command]
    void CmdSelectCharacter(string warrior, int slot)
    { 
        RpcUpdateOpponentCharacter(warrior, slot);
        
    }

    [ClientRpc]
    void RpcUpdateOpponentCharacter(string warrior, int slot)
    {
        Enemies.PutEnemiesInScene(warrior, slot);
        
    }
}

Cuando corro la aplicación y elijo Server/Cliente en el hud de Mirror todo funciona de maravilla, pero cuando genero otro cliente desde la Build solo pasa a tener prioridad ese cliente, ya el server no refleja los cambios, y si sigo agregando cientes solo el ultimo es el que tiene el permiso de hacer los cambios.
Agradeceria cualquier tipo de ayuda.
